# Control what text is shown on hover

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have made a Google maps with 3 red pin-points on. When a person is hovering over a pin-point there is coming HTML code, that is not looking pretty good. Example from one of the pins:

`Lorem Ipsum 3<br>.   Adress 3 <br>.  <a href=“####” target=“_blank”>Vis vej</a>`

A demosite can be [seen here](http://vouzalis.dk/stack.html)

Is it possible to set some kind of `alt` tag in the javascript, so I can control what is shown when a person hover over the pin points?

```
function initMap() {
      var center = {lat: 51.487655, lng: -0.088128};
      var locations = [

        ['Lorem Ipsum 1<br>\
        Adress 1<br>\
        <a href="####" target="_blank">Vis vej</a>',   52.192877, -0.893615],

        ['Lorem Ipsum 2<br>\
        Adress 2 <br>\
        <a href="#####" target="_blank">Vis vej</a>',   51.627608, -0.501912],

        ['Lorem Ipsum 3<br>\
        Adress 3 <br>\
        <a href="####" target="_blank">Vis vej</a>',   51.483280, -0.071244],

      ];
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 7,
        center: center
      });
    var infowindow =  new google.maps.InfoWindow({});
    var marker, count;
    for (count = 0; count < locations.length; count++) {
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[count][1], locations[count][2]),
          map: map,
          title: locations[count][0]
        });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, count) {
          return function () {
            infowindow.setContent(locations[count][0]);
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
          }
        })(marker, count));
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hover text is set by the marker's title property which is text only (no HTML).  Don't put HTML tags in there, with your code, one option would be to assign a different array element to it that just contains text:

```
var locations = [
    ['Lorem Ipsum 1', 
     'Lorem Ipsum 1<br>Adress 1<br><a href="####" target="_blank">Vis vej</a>',
     52.192877, -0.893615],
    ['Lorem Ipsum 2', 
     'Lorem Ipsum 2<br>Adress 2 <br><a href="#####" target="_blank">Vis vej</a>', 
     51.627608, -0.501912],
    ['Lorem Ipsum 3', 
     'Lorem Ipsum 3<br>Adress 3 <br><a href="####" target="_blank">Vis vej</a>', 
     51.483280, -0.071244],
  ];
```

Then create your markers like this:

```
for (count = 0; count < locations.length; count++) {
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[count][2], locations[count][3]),
    map: map,
    title: locations[count][0]
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, count) {
    return function() {
      infowindow.setContent(locations[count][1]);
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
    }
  })(marker, count));
}
```

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/rjp751wb/)

[image: screenshot of resulting map]

**code snippet:**

```js
function initMap() {
  var center = {
    lat: 51.487655,
    lng: -0.088128
  };
  var locations = [
    ['Lorem Ipsum 1', 'Lorem Ipsum 1<br>Adress 1<br><a href="####" target="_blank">Vis vej</a>', 52.192877, -0.893615],
    ['Lorem Ipsum 2', 'Lorem Ipsum 2<br>Adress 2 <br><a href="#####" target="_blank">Vis vej</a>', 51.627608, -0.501912],
    ['Lorem Ipsum 3', 'Lorem Ipsum 3<br>Adress 3 <br><a href="####" target="_blank">Vis vej</a>', 51.483280, -0.071244],
  ];
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 7,
    center: center
  });
  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({});
  var marker, count;
  for (count = 0; count < locations.length; count++) {
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[count][2], locations[count][3]),
      map: map,
      title: locations[count][0]
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, count) {
      return function() {
        infowindow.setContent(locations[count][1]);
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
      }
    })(marker, count));
  }
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you a lot for this. Solved the problem beautifully.